# framework 7 action sheet not working

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

framwork 7 visit https://framework7.io/docs/action-sheet.html

actionsheet open but not working on other page to come this page. I think not initialize in page view

this is my js code

```
$$('.demo-actions').on('click', function () {
var buttons = [
    {
        text: 'Short By:',
        label: true
    },
    {
        text: 'XYZ',
        bold:true,
    },
    {
        text: 'ABC',
        bold:true,

    },
    {
        text: '123',
        bold:true,
    },
    {
        text: 'abc',
        color: 'red'
    },
];
myApp.actions(buttons);
```

});

this is html code

```
<a href="#" class="demo-actions buttons ">XYZ</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution here :

```js
$$(document).on('pageInit', function(e) {
    refreshCalls();
});
refreshCalls();

function refreshCalls() {
    /* ===== Action sheet, we use it on dashboard pages ===== */
    $$('.demo-actions').on('click', function() {
        var buttons = [{
            text: 'Short By:',
            label: true
        }, {
            text: 'XYZ',
            bold: true,
        }, {
            text: 'ABC',
            bold: true,

        }, {
            text: '123',
            bold: true,
        }, {
            text: 'abc',
            color: 'red'
        }, ];
        myApp.actions(buttons);
    });
}
```